# How to run xsl in browser

Tags: xml, eclipse, xslt

I am working with xml and dtd and understand the concepts pretty well but totally new to xsl and xslts . 
Today i created a simple project in Eclipse that has three files , test.xml, test.dtd,test.xsl.
I Ran test.xsl as "XSL Transformation" which ran successfully and i got one output file. called test.out.xml. But i dont know what to do next? 
More i am reading i am getting confused. I know ofcourse one way is to make some java program to use it( which i dont want to do)
I just simply want to see the output in browser. IS there no simple way to just test it rather than going in coding details? Any tool, or online way?
Is it possible? 
Please can someone guide me. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There is. If you serve the files to the browser with correct MIME types and the `xsl-stylesheet` heading and the NoScript add on trusts your site, it'll work.

Comment: how can i do it in chrome?